# Algorithm to fully populate 100% of window with controls (button, etc) dynamically

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic, grid

Say I want to create a grid of an object, say buttons. I know the Window width and height and I know the amount of buttons there is to add.

Is there any smart algorithm to calculate each button's width and height according to this? I'm trying to come up with something but all I'm getting is left over blank space when I really want to populate the whole window.

No matter the object, in this case I use buttons for simplicity.

Simply put, I want to fill the whole screen with an object (a button). If there's only one button that button would populate the whole screen, two buttons would share the size.

And, if I want to change the value next run to more buttons it should still fill up the whole screen then too.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you want your controls to equaly (or almost) share the window's space?

Comment: What UI framework are you using? Pretty much any of them should provide layout managers that could handle that for you. Another question: how do you want your objects to be distributed? All in a single line? Multiple columns and multiple rows? You need to be more specific.

Comment: If I have a window of 500x500 and about 20 or 10 controls. They should be distributed equally. Like a grid.

Comment: I was thinking about the aspect ratio of the window, and distributing the buttons that way but I have no idea how. So they look "normal" and not some of the buttons are 2 pixels in width and 20 in height.

Comment: I'm just using C++, not with Forms or anything. So I create my buttons with CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON")...);

Answer (score 1):

If you have one row of buttons you only need to divide the width of the window by the number of buttons and set all of the buttons width to that value.

```
button.width  = window.width / numberOfButtons;
button.height = window.height;
```

If you have multiple rows just do the same with the height;

```
button.width  = window.width  / numberOfButtonsH;
button.height = window.height / numberOfButtonsV;
```

When you want the buttons to have more reasonable sizes, try using the square root of the desired number of buttons for the amount of buttons in one row. If the desired number of buttons is uneven you add another row and center the last button in this row.

For seventeen buttons you would have five rows, four buttons per row in the first four rows, and one button in the last row.

It could be done like this (edited to use temporary data structure):

```
int width  = 600;//replace those values with your own dimensions
int height = 600;

inline bool isUneven(const int i)
{
    return (i%2);
}

struct tempButton
{
    int x,y,w,h;
};

void populateWindow( const int requestedObjects = 18 )
{
    int objectsPerRow       = (int)floor(sqrt(requestedObjects));
    int rows = objectsPerRow;

    int diff = requestedObjects-rows*objectsPerRow;

    tempButton tmp[requestedObjects];

    if(diff>0)
    {
        ++rows;// only needed for button dimension calculation, will be changed later
    }

    int buttonWidth  = width  / objectsPerRow;
    int buttonHeight = height / rows;
    int lastRowWidth = 0; width / diff;

    for(int i=0; i<requestedObjects-diff; ++i)
    {
        tmp[i].h = buttonHeight;
        tmp[i].w = buttonWidth;
    }
    if(diff>0)
    {
        lastRowWidth = width / diff;
        for(int i=requestedObjects-diff; i<requestedObjects; ++i)
        {
            tmp[i].h = buttonHeight;
            tmp[i].w = lastRowWidth;
        }
        --rows; // subtract one, because placing the last button on its own is easier
    }
    for(int i=0; i<rows; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<objectsPerRow; ++j)
        {
            tmp[j+i*objectsPerRow].x = j*buttonWidth;        // set the positions
            tmp[j+i*objectsPerRow].y = i*buttonHeight;
        }
    }
    if(diff>0)
    {
        for(int i=requestedObjects-diff; i<requestedObjects; ++i)
        {
            tmp[i].x = (i-(requestedObjects-diff))*lastRowWidth;
            tmp[i].y = rows*buttonHeight;
        }

    }

    // now create the buttons using the temporary data

}
```

Comment: That's a weak answer, how would your algorithm render 17 controls, wisely distributed?

Comment: I don't see the difference than what I previously had. You've given me the layout but there's no algorithm.

Comment: Also, the code is more C# than C++. The buttons are no class. I can only set the ID, X, Y and Size when I create them.

Comment: CreateWindow(Type, Text, Style, x, y, size_x, size_y, parent, hMenu, Instance, lpParam);

Comment: You can make a temporary datastructure to save those values and then create the buttons at the end of the function. I will edit my post according to that.

Comment: @Deukalion: I don't see what makes you think this code is "more C# than C++". C++ can be (and often is) used in an object-oriented way. Have a look at some high-level UI framework such as [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/), which uses objects to represents UI widgets (and is not Windows-specific, unlike the functions you seem to be using).

Comment: This wasn't exactly the layout I was thinking of, which is the result of this method: http://postimage.org/image/hg1dpjtkv/

Comment: After copying pasting your method, it works. But whenever I change the value to say, 18. I don't get 18 buttons I get 4x4.

Comment: Just to say, it only works with "uneven" buttons. 17 = works fine, 18 = 16, 19 = 17, 20 = 16, 21 = 17, 22 = 16, 23 = 17, 24 = 16, 25 = a 4x5 grid, then the last row is 4 buttons, and then below that one is the button that should have been beside the other four buttons. Example of 25: http://postimage.org/image/oo7oq0tjn/ (and I've just copied this method and changed the name to the names I use.)

Comment: The error is that there are numbers that are not uneven and neither a squared number. I will update my post with a fix.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need some more rules.

The number of controls has to be a product of two other numbers, so as someone suggested 17 gives you only 17 * 1, so then button width is gridth width / 17 and button height is window height or vice versa if you'd prefer one column.

You could try and do something with aspect ratio to make this more sense e.g. width > height means you should go for a row.

If the number of controls is a product then it will either be a square or again you can use width / height to calcu out the button widths and heights.

You might also want to consider minimum width and height for the buttons, but then you have more won't fit problems. If you want some padding round each button, just calculate that and then centree the button within it.